# Power Supply Not Working?

Tags: troubleshooting, power-supply

So I recently made some purchases for a new computer including:

- **Motherboard:** Gigabyte GA-EP45-UD3R
- **CPU :** Intel Core2Quad 2.66Ghz
- **Power Supply:** Antec Basiq 500w

**UPDATE:** I got the Power Supply working, the motherboard's lights come on, the video card fan spins, BUT the CPU fan does NOT spin and there is no video. Whats the possibility of lacking power? In the mobo guide it says the use of a power supply providing a 2x4 12V connector is recommended (I do not have this connector) by the CPU manufacturer when using an Intel Extreme Edition (I'm using Core2Quad)

**UPDATE:** Got it working, intstalling windows 7 now. THANKS GUYS!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware all Core 2 processors will need the 4 or 8 pin power connector plugged into the motherboard.

Without it you will get similar symptoms to your issue.

Look on your power supply for a 4 or 8 pin plug. It will be on its own cable.
It will either be a 2x2 or 2x4 pin plug

```
X X
X X
```

or

```
X X X X
X X X X
```

The connector on the motherboard is generally located near the CPU socket.

It will probably be an 8 pin connector, but 4 of the pins may be covered with a small piece of plastic.

If the power supply has a 4 pin connector, just plug it in.
If the power supply has an 8 pin connector, remove the cover from the motherboard, then plug in.

The connector will only go in one way, and there are no other connectors on the motherboard that are similar.

Answer (score 3):

Short pins 4 and 6 with a piece of wire (green and the one two holes to the right). Do it carefully or prepare for unforseen consequences.

If the PSU and plugged-in drives spin up, the supply works.

Also mess around with what auxilliary connectors are plugged into the mobo. There's a 4- or 8-pin CPU plug that you absolutely need. There's a 4-pin molex that sometimes is needed, but sometimes makes it not work.

*[edit: Pin numbers 4 and 6 are as counted WITHOUT the ATX+4 attachment.]*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Curiously there is a [TomsHardware discussion](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/252594-29-ep45-ud3r) on the
"antec basiq 500 watt" running a "GA EP45-UD3R" that does not overclock.
So, it must be booting in the first place.

There is [another discussion on the 12V rail too](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/250239-29-gigabyte-ep45-ud3r-abnormal-voltages).
But, again this is an overclock discussion where the board seems to be working
(and, with a different PSU)