# Power supply failure

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure

New everything! LED lights green on motherboard when power is turned on. BUT THAT'S ALL! No fans moving, no hard drive spinning, no indication of any other power. No resonse from anything. Again,
newly built system. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the power button is plugged in the right two pins on the motherboard. If so, remove it and short circuit the 2 pins to see if it is not the power button not working.

Another thing you can do and solves a lot of problems of this kind (capacitor problems usually) is to remove the power cable from the wall and turn the the computer on a few times (without reconecting the power plug). After that you plug the power cable in the wall and try to turn the machine on.

You said it's a new system but did it work at least once?

Comment: It has never worked...except for the green LED light on the motherboard...when the power is turned on, it lights up....off and it goes out.

Answer (score 1):

Are all the power cables connected properly? Had the same problem once, the problem was that the main board cable wasn't connected properly.

Comment: Also make sure you attached the 4 or 8-pin CPU power cord. (Don't confuse with an 8-pin PCI-e power cord! The pins are shaped differently, so simply don't force it.)

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that this could be due to any number of causes:

- Defective power supply. Test it independently (see below).
- Defective motherboard. The power supply won't start if it doesn't see a load from the motherboard (see below).
- Defective cables, or incorrectly used. That one's usually straightforward, but double-check the power connector requirements in the motherboard's manual.
- A short somewhere on the motherboard. Check for moisture, metal scraps, etc. I once that this happen from mounting screws with ever so slightly too wide heads.

The power supply won't start if it doesn't see a load on a particular pin. The topic's come up here many times before; see [How to test a power supply?](https://superuser.com/questions/23788/how-to-test-a-power-supply), and also [a diagram](https://superuser.com/questions/35480/power-supply-not-working/35495#35495).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will be kind but it a simple problem that happened to me a lot of time. I check your post and get attention to: it's new everything and only green led displays.

TURN the voltage switch to 115v!